# React type tester only receiving one input then stopping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keydown

So I'm not sure why my code isn't taking into subsequent keydowns, it takes the first 'l' then just stops:

I honestly don't know what the issue is. The lorem is a long string that I turn into an array, then if "e.key" === array item at 0, remove that item and update position.

I don't know why this isn't being done for every keydown.

```
import { useState } from "react"

const Input = ({text}) => {
    const [lorem,changeString] = useState(text.split(''))
    const [input,changeInput] = useState('')
    const [position,changePosition] = useState(0)
    const [color,changeColor] = useState(false)

    const keyDown = (e) => {
        changeInput(e.key)
        compareCharacters(input)
    }

    const compareCharacters = (input) => {
        if (input === lorem[position]) {
            changeString(lorem.splice(0,1))
            changePosition(position+1)
        } else {
            changeColor(true)
        }
    }


  return (
    <input className={`text ${color ? 'new' : ''}`}
    type="text" 
    size="10000"
    onKeyDown={keyDown}
    >
    </input>
  )
}

export default Input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const Input = ({ text }) => {
  const [lorem, changeString] = useState(text.split(''))
  const [position, changePosition] = useState(0)
  const [color, changeColor] = useState(false)

  const keyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key !== lorem[position]) {
      changeColor(true)
      return
    }
    changeString(lorem.slice(1))
    changePosition(position + 1)
  }



  return (
    <input
      className={`text ${color ? 'new' : ''}`}
      type="text"
      size={10000}
      onKeyDown={keyDown}
    ></input>
  )
}

export default Input
```

Comment: I've managed to get it to work, splice was returning an array of 1 item every time.

Comment: yeah, I missed that part. splice function mutates the array. It shouldn't be used on state without copying.

Comment: I've come across another problem. Is it possible to block all keydown input from the user save the one we want?

Comment: @ether save the one we want?

Comment: except the one we want* (another way of saying that)

Comment: I edited the code, If I understand the goal correctly like this.